# How to write Regular Expression for number,characters,alphanumeric

Tags: regex, zend-framework

I am using Zend_Validate_Regex, I need the regular expression which has the following check,

1. 123456 - Accepted
2. 12345A - Accepted
3. A12345 - Accepted
4. ABCDEF - Accepted

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `(?i)^[\da-f]+$`

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting an hexadecimal number, the regular expression is:

```
/[0-9A-F]*/
```

May be, you want to use also non capital letters:

```
/[0-9A-F]*/i
```

Or perhaps you want to use exactly 6 characters (numbers and letters):

```
/[0-9A-F]{6}/i
```